# How does calculating a FOR loop sentinel affect complexity

Tags: algorithm

Let's say we have a FOR loop

```
int n;

for (int i = 0; i < sqrt(n); i++)
{
    statement;
}
```

Does calculating the sqrt of i add complexity to the loop's O(n) complexity? In my example the sqrt function in Java has a time complexity of O(log n), how does this affect the time complexity of the loop? Is the sqrt function applied for every sequence of the loop or just once and that value is stored and used again?

Comment: Are you modifying `n` inside of `statement`?

Comment: Let's say that n is not changed in the statement.

Comment: (I don't see a loop sentinel: an element created or modified to save one evaluation in the termination condition. Example: Searching an ordered singly linked list given a _key_ and references to _head_ and _tail_. Instead of comparing to _tail_ or _nil_ in each iteration, set the last element to _key_ or append such an element and search without bother about _end of list_.)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this can depend on language but generally `i < sqrt(n)` check will be ran after each loop's iteration so effectively you'll call it `sqrt(n)` times. Good idea is to store `sqrt(n)` result in variable and compare it to `i`, so

```
int n;
double sn = sqrt(n);

for (int i = 0; i < sn; i++)
{
    statement;
}
```

Comment: So this means that it will take time for every iteration to calculate the same value before executing the statement right?

Comment: @cheroz it's possible for your compiler to optimize the `sqrt` call out of the loop if it can determine that there are no side effects and the value of the argument can't change. But it's always better to make it explicit and remove all doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The sqrt function is applied for every sequence of the loop. The use of `n` is different though. The complexity of `O(logn)` for the sqrt has `n` being the number of bits in the value, but the `O(n)` of the loop has `n` being the actual value. With that definition of `n`, then the sqrt is more like `O(loglogn)`.

For loops like these, the complexity of operations on numbers like sqrt can be treated as constant time. The number of bits is bounded so the time is insignificant compared to the larger loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the variable n given in the question,

O(**log(d=bits of variable)** * **sqrt(n=number in the loop)**)

assuming finding n-digit(bits) numbers' sqrt is log(D) as 'fgb' said first.

**Assuming** n's number of bits are constant all through the computation and for all hardwares, so:

O(log(constant) * sqrt (n))

O(constant * sqrt(n))

O(sqrt(n))

But if it is not strongly-styped and if n's bits is increased gradually(such as going from 64 bit to 128 to 256 bit to 1024 but having same value) then it would be

O(log(d)*sqrt(n))

Comment: What if the sqrt function is not a library/hardware function, let's say it uses binary search to calculate the sqrt and thus has O(log n) time complexity? I'm sorry if I'm slow to grasp this but I'm just starting to learn about algorithms.

Comment: Its square root n if number of bits stay same for all computation.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering your question about time complexity**

`sqrt(n)` is called once each iteration, and this will take some additionally time.

But since `sqrt(n)` is independent from `i` or any other value in the `statement`, the calculation takes always the same amount of time. So from my understaning it does **not increase the complexity** of the loop, it is still O(n).